# Optional parameters without default values - PHP

Tags: php, function

I am facing some confusion regarding methods or functions I have come across, which accept parameters with some being optional. Upon inspecting the function declaration i do not see any default values.

For example I am using a PDO object.

```
$dbh = new PDO( $dsn,$username,$password,$option );
```

Excerpt from PDO class

```
class PDO {

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0, PECL pdo &gt;= 0.1.0)<br/>
 * Creates a PDO instance representing a connection to a database
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php
 *
 * @param $dsn
 * @param $username [optional]
 * @param $passwd [optional]
 * @param $options [optional]
 */
public function __construct( $dsn, $username, $passwd, $options ) {
}

}
```

On the surface I can not see how the parameters have been set as optional (other than the constructor method's comments). It is my understanding that parameters must always be provided if required or if not a default value must be set. I am still in the early stages of learning programming and would really appreciate if someone could explain the reasoning behind this or what I am missing.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Where does your excerpt from the PDO class come from?

Comment: I am using the phpstorm IDE, which allows you to 'goTo' the declaration of a function which in turn took me to something called an 'immutable embedded stub'. I noticed the 'stub' appears to have only the declarations as placeholders.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be something like that. The thing is, PDO is a built-in class in PHP, and is actually implemented in C, not PHP. The stub generated by the IDE isn't the actual code for the constructor. As far as PHP is concerned, your understanding is correct. The only way for a parameter to be optional is to provide a default value.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oh, I see, pretty interesting. Thank you very much for the clarification. (admittedly I was hoping there might be some fancy alternative way of achieving optional parameters, which i was not aware of).

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know another way to define optional _named_ parameters, but you are able to pass more parameters than you have defined in the function signature and get them with `func_get_args`, and you can also use variable-length argument lists. Those things aren't really applicable to this example, but just FYI.